# Read first not empty line from file and store in XML

Tags: python, xml, readline

I should create a Script that collects data about files in a certain folder and store them in an xml file, which is created during the process.

I am stuck at the point, at which the first sentence of the file should be stored in .

The files have one sentence per line, but some start with empty lines. The files with empty lines would need to store the first non empty line.
This is my attempt:

```
    first_sent = et.SubElement(file_corpus, 'firstsentence')
    text = open(filename, 'rU')

    first_sent.text=text.readline() #this line was before if!!

    if text.readline() != '':
        print text.readline()

        first_sent.text = text.readline()
```

Currently it only some (random) sentence for very few files.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling text.readline() again instead of checking the value previously read.  And you need a loop in order to skip all the blank lines.

Something resembling this should work:

```
first_sent = et.SubElement(file_corpus, 'firstsentence')
text = open(filename, 'rU')

first_sent.text=text.readline() #this line was before if!!

while first_sent.text == '':
    first_sent.text = text.readline()
```